# Show lines with values per category

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
           Genre           Variabelen       Value
1 4am Comedown              std_acc 0.253673983
2 4am Comedown              std_val 0.230741321
3 4am Comedown           std_energy 0.203915405
4 4am Comedown     std_danceability 0.185097424
5 4am Comedown std_instrumentalness  0.32926114 
6 4am Comedown      std_speechiness 0.059602086
```

What I would like to do now is create a linegraph of the values per genre where the x-axis contains the "variabelen". So the legend should contain the Genre.

For this Im using the following line:

```
library(ggplot)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Variabelen, y=Value)) + geom_line(aes(colour=Genre))
```

This however gives me now lines and the following warming:

```
geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

Any thoughts on where I go wrong?

Comment: are you sure you did not use geom_path() ? we don't have access to your data, please use dput()

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `group=Genre` in the aes:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Variabelen, y=Value, group=Genre, colour=Genre)) + geom_line()
```